# mod-rewrite RewriteBase not working correctly from root

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite, xampp

Hi I have been following the ["Build a PHP MVC Application"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRgHBu3msA4) tutorial on Codecourse's YouTube Channel.

I have moved the project to the root(htdocs)
and now when I load http://localhost all I see is the default apache folder index.

My files are organised as such:

```
htdocs
->app
->public
->.htaccess
```

.htacces contains:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Edit: if I go to localhost/home (one of the controllers i setup) it loads the page correctly

Comment: Does the file `public/index.php` exist?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Yeah the file is there another thing that I forgot to mention is that if I go to http://localhost/home (one of the controllers i setup) it loads the page correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rewritable part http://localhost/ is empty, so it does not match (.+).
It would match (.*).

Comment: Thanks after removing `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and changing the Regex string everything is working thanks man